# "undefined reference to `gtk_label_set_xalign'" when compiling a Vala application

Tags: user-interface, cmake, alignment, label, vala

I am writing a Vala application and I use labels in it. Here is the constructor (I guess that is the place which causes the error):

```
titleLabel = new Gtk.Label("");
titleLabel.set_markup(wrapInTags(post.title));
titleLabel.set_line_wrap(true);
titleLabel.wrap_mode = Pango.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR;
titleLabel.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.LEFT);
//titleLabel.set_max_width_chars(40);
titleLabel.set_xalign(0);
```

And when I compile it, this happens:

```
CMakeFiles/photostream.dir/Widgets/PostBox.c.o: In function `photo_stream_widgets_post_box_construct':
PostBox.c:(.text+0x2111): undefined reference to `gtk_label_set_xalign'
CMakeFiles/photostream.dir/Widgets/CommentsBox.c.o: In function `photo_stream_widgets_comment_box_construct':
CommentsBox.c:(.text+0x1045): undefined reference to `gtk_label_set_xalign'
CMakeFiles/photostream.dir/Widgets/NewsBox.c.o: In function `photo_stream_widgets_news_box_construct':
NewsBox.c:(.text+0x1af8): undefined reference to `gtk_label_set_xalign'
CMakeFiles/photostream.dir/Windows/BulkDownloadWindow.c.o: In function `photo_stream_bulk_download_window_construct':
BulkDownloadWindow.c:(.text+0x14b1): undefined reference to `gtk_label_set_xalign'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to replace last string with `titleLabel.xalign = 0`, but the result is still the same.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems I found the answer, according to this: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html the `gtk_label_set_xalign()` method is available since GTK+ 3.16 and I was using 3.14.